# use of undeclared identifier 'NSEntityDescription'

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I've been banging my head against this for too long.  I have two ViewControllers trying to use NSEntityDescription, one can and one can't (giving me the above error).

Both ViewControllers import AppDelegate.h

I figure that it has to be a problem with the ManagedObjectContext but both ViewControllers set the ManagedObjectContext in ViewDidLoad the same way:

```
if (!self.managedObjectContext) {
        self.managedObjectContext =  [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }
```

Maybe it has to do with the view controller hierarchy?  Tho, I'm under the assumption that the use of NSEntityDescription is based upon the managedObjectContext.

Thanks!

Comment: I typically add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to my Prefix.pch to ensure that it's available to all classes. It sounds like you forgot to import the Core Data headers in one of the view controllers.

Comment: Oh my goodness that was it.  It was nestled within another #imported file.  I think I'll take your advice.  Why don't you make you comment an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I typically add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to my Prefix.pch to ensure that it's available to all classes. It sounds like you forgot to import the Core Data headers in one of the view controllers.

Comment: in case of swift for a particular controller want to use the just add import CoreData